# Почему работает неправильно 1?

Tags: java, массивы

Вечер добрый, почему выводит неправильно? Где ошибка? Не перезаписывает массив задом на перед!

```
int[] err = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int g = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[err.length];
        for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--){
                arr[g] = err[err.length - i];
                g++;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
```

Comment: Сорри, но дебагером пользоваться не учили? Ставить точки остановки, чтоб отладить программу и понять, где ошибка. Еще логи сильно помогают, но в данном случае лучше дебагер использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что

`i = 5, g = 0`

```
 arr[0] = err[0];
```

`i = 4, g = 1`

```
 arr[1] = err[1];
```

`i = 3, g = 2`

```
 arr[2] = err[2];
```

`...`

---

```
    for (int i = 0; i < err.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = err[err.length - 1 - i];
    }
```

Второй счетчик не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] err = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int g = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[err.length];
    for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--){
        arr[g] = err[err.length - (g+1)];
        g++;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
```